# How can I allow only a single instance of a React component to be present?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a functionality in react.

The problem goes like this: I have three components ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC. ComponentC can be rendered as a child of either ComponentA or ComponentB.

What I want to achieve is that at any point of time there is only one instance of ComponentC present in the DOM, can be either as a child of ComponentA or ComponentB, both of which are always present.

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentC />
    );
  }
}

class ComponentB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentC />
    );
  }
}

class ComponentC extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is ComponentC </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to build a way to unmount any instance of ComponentC (if present) whenever it is mounted but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Maybe this [singleton](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-singleton) package will help you? The singleton design pattern ensures that you have only one instance of a given class.

Comment: Do `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` share the same props? Or do they only share `ComponentC` as a child?

Comment: @mersocarlin they have nothing in common except ComponentC

Comment: can't you just hide(or set into some 'empty' state) one of the two ComponentC's ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes As far as my knowledge goes, react doesn't allow direct communication between components belonging to different parents. That's where global state management concepts like flux & redux come in. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: this seems not correct to me; the most obvious way being via events ( C fires an event up to some common ancestor X that set its state and propagate down props accordingly ); if you cannot pass those events from X down to C, then you probably have a design flaw. Anyway, once mounted, components are regular javascript objects and they can communicate at will ( for example, via a WeakSet ), you just need special care to manually manage their lifetimes/states.

Answer (score 5):

Implementing a reference counter with hooks does the job:

```js
function Highlander(Component) {
  let immortals = 0
  return function(props) {
    const [onlyOne, thereIsOnlyOne] = React.useState(false)
    React.useEffect(() => {
      immortals++
      if (immortals === 1) {
        thereIsOnlyOne(true)
      }
      () => {
        immortals--
      }
    }, [])
    return onlyOne ? <Component { ...props}/> : <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
  }
}

function Test() {
  return "test"
}

const OnlyOneTest = Highlander(Test)

ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <OnlyOneTest />
  <OnlyOneTest />
  <OnlyOneTest />
</React.Fragment>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Starring Highlander as a HoC, which "singletons" the composed component (get the Highlander reference ? uhuh).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this. The simplest method that comes to mind is simply to check the DOM if said node exists. If it exists, just render nothing or prevent the state from toggling it.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showA: false,
      showB: false
    };
  }
  
  toggleA = () => {
    if(document.getElementById("component_c") && !this.state.showA) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({showA: !prevState.showA}));
  }
  
  toggleB = () => {
    if(document.getElementById("component_c") && !this.state.showB) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({showB: !prevState.showB}));
  }
 
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.toggleA}>Show/Hide A</button>
          <button onClick={this.toggleB}>Show/Hide B</button>
        </div>
        {this.state.showA && <ComponentA />}
        {this.state.showB && <ComponentB />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentC parent="A" />
    );
  }
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentC parent="B" />
    );
  }
}

class ComponentC extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="component_c">{"This is ComponentC, rendered from component" + this.props.parent}</div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: it's closer to what I am looking for but not exactly that, singleton package suggested by @VTodorov is what I need